# Space Invader Errors

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

So I got the basics of Space Inavder down and coded it with OOP and tkinter. However Im running into the issue that when one of the bullets hit the entire program just freezes. Ive tried to debug the code but I cant seem to find the issue and a long term solution.

I tried to use the after() function to produce an infitie loop to stop it from freezing that didnt work. I tried to modify game_loop that also didnt work. The issue here is that after it hits one of the red circles the entire console freezes. You can test out the code for yourself.

```
import tkinter as tkimport time
import random

class Game:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Space Invaders")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=600, height=600, bg="black")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.player = Player(self.canvas)
        self.enemies = [Enemy(self.canvas) for _ in range(5)]
        self.bullets = []
        self.master.bind("<Left>", self.move_left)
        self.master.bind("<Right>", self.move_right)
        self.master.bind("<space>", self.shoot)
        self.game_loop()

    def move_left(self, event):
        self.player.move(-20)

    def move_right(self, event):
        self.player.move(20)

    def shoot(self, event):
        bullet = Bullet(self.canvas, self.player.x, self.player.y)
        self.bullets.append(bullet)

    def game_loop(self):
        for enemy in self.enemies:
            enemy.move()
            for bullet in self.bullets:
                if bullet.check_collision(enemy):
                    self.enemies.remove(enemy)
                    self.canvas.delete(enemy.id)
                    self.bullets.remove(bullet)
                    self.canvas.delete(bullet.id)
            if self.player.check_collision(enemy):
                self.canvas.delete("all")
                self.canvas.create_text(300, 300, text="Game Over", fill="white", font=("Helvetica", 36))
                return
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.move()
        self.canvas.update()
        self.master.after(100, self.game_loop)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(275, 550, 325, 600, fill="blue")
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 575

    def move(self, dx):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, dx, 0)
        self.x += dx

    def check_collision(self, other):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        other_coords = other.get_coords()
        return (x1 < other_coords[2] and x2 > other_coords[0]) and (y1 < other_coords[3] and y2 > other_coords[1])


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(275, 25, 325, 75, fill="red")
        self.x = random.randint(0, 550)
        self.y = 50
        self.dx = random.choice([-20, 20])

    def move(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.dx, 0)
        self.x += self.dx
        if self.x >= 550 or self.x <= 0:
            self.dx *= -1

    def get_coords(self):
        return self.canvas.coords(self.id)


class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 5, y + 10, fill="yellow")
        self.y_speed = -20

    def move(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y_speed)
        if self.canvas.coords(self.id)[1] < 0:
            self.canvas.delete(self.id)

    def check_collision(self, other):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        other_coords = other.get_coords()
        return (x1 < other_coords[2] and x2 > other_coords[0]) and (y1 < other_coords[3] and y2 > other_coords[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    game = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The shown code is syntactically incorrect, the program wouldn't even start.

Comment: In `game_loop()` think what will happen on the line `if self.player.check_collision(enemy)` if `enemy` is deleted.  Also inside `Bullet.move()`, if the bullet is deleted, then what will happen in `game_loop()` if this bullet is being moved (because it still exists in `bullets` list.

Comment: line 104, in check_collision
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

Comment: at least part of the problem is that you're changing a list while at the same time iterating over that list.